# Cordova: Problems with GoogleService-info.plist

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, firebase, phonegap-pushplugin

Currently, I'm working on an app. For the notifications I've been using **phonegap-plugin-push** combined with **Firebase**.

I'm using this plugin for Android as well as iOS. On Android it works perfectly fine, sure I've been experiencing problems, but got it all done now. IOS on the other hand won't work. The app won't even build.

If I build I get this error:

> ** BUILD FAILED**
>
> The following build commands failed:
>
> CopyPlistFile
> /Users/gio/app/Project/platforms/ios/build/emulator/Project.app/GoogleService-Info.plist
> /Users/gio/App/App/Project/platforms/ios/Project/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist
> (1 failure)
>
> Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:
> -xcconfig,/Users/gio/app/Project/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Project.xcworkspace,-scheme,Project,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS
> Simulator, name = iPhone
> SE,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/gio/app/Project/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/gio/app/Project/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

As you can notice the path that the app is searching for has a double "root" (/App/App/)

I guess that the programming is trying to put of get something to of from a path that doesn't exist.

The strange thing is that it works on Android without any problems and it won't work on iOS.

**Cordova version: 7.0.1**

**Cordova iOS version: 4.4.0**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure that you have this in your config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</platform>
```

And that your GoogleService-Info.plist file is at the root of your app [via documentation](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md).

If this doesn't work for you, I would suggest trying [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) instead. I have used both and find cordova-plugin-fcm to work best.

Comment: I've already added that during the installation. It appears that cordova version 4.4.0 has a bug. It will be fixed in the next update.